# Добавление внешней библиотеки QT

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qtcreator

форумчане. Хочу узнать как в QT(Windows) можно добавить внешнюю либу, скажу сразу QT до этого не использовал.

Библиотека которую хочу добавить(работа с пдф): https://github.com/libharu/libharu

До этого смотрел подобные вопросы, но там предлагали забить в командную строку и указать напрямую путь к длл, хотя в моём случае я в скаченном решении даже длл не нашёл, по этому буду рад, если детально опишите действия, спасибо!

Comment: Спросите у гугла/яндекса *"Добавление внешней библиотеки Qt"*

Comment: Спрашивал, там все пишут огромные команды , которые мало того что непонятно куда вводятся и в какой последовательности и почему так, так ещё и либо что я хочу ставить немного специфичная

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После того как вы соберете вашу библиотеку, то cможете подключить ее к проекту на Qt следующими способами.

**qmake**. В файле сборки проекта (файле с расширением pro) добавьте следующие строки:

```
INCLUDEPATH += <Путь/до/заголовочных/файлов/библиотеки>

LIBS += -L<Путь/до/папки/с/либами> -l<имялибы>
```

Здесь `<имялибы>` - это название библиотеки без префикса `lib и расширения`. Например, ваша либа на диске имеет имя `libharu.a`, тогда вместо `<имялибы>` вы указываете `haru` и получается `-lharu`

Можно воспользоваться сборкой проекта при помощи **cmake**, но я с ним работал очень мало и сказать точно, что и как там делается не могу.